# python tuple immutable but set type attribute can be changed

Tags: python, attributes, set, namedtuple

I understand that a namedtuple in python is immutable and the values of its attributes cant be reassigned directly

```
N = namedtuple("N",['ind','set','v'])
def solve()
    items=[]
    R = set(range(0,8))
    for i in range(0,8):
        items.append(N(i,R,8))  
    items[0].set.remove(1)
    items[0].v+=1
```

Here last like where I am assigning a new value to **attribute 'v'** will not work. But removing the element '**1' from the set** attribute of items[0] works.

Why is that and will this be true if set attribute were of List type

Comment: Remember: you are not changing the tuple, but the object inside the tuple.

Comment: Note that a `tuple` that contains a mutable object isn't hashable. Try to put it inside a `dict` and you'll get an error. Immutable containers are truly immutable (and thus possibly hashable) if and only if all their elements are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immutability does not get conferred on mutable objects inside the tuple. *All* immutability means is you can't change which particular objects are stored - ie, you can't reassign `items[0].set`. This restriction is the same regardless of the type of that variable - if it was a list, doing `items[0].list = items[0].list + [1,2,3]` would fail (can't reassign it to a new object), but doing `items[0].list.extend([1,2,3])` would work.

Think about it this way: if you change your code to:
    new_item = N(i,R,8)

then `new_item.set` is now an alias for R (Python doesn't copy objects when you reassign them). If tuples conferred immutability to mutable members, what would you expect `R.remove(1)` to do? Since it is *the same set* as `new_item.set`, any changes you make to one will be visible in the other. If the set had become immutable because it has become a member of a tuple, `R.remove(1)` would suddenly fail. All method calls in Python work or fail depending on the object only, not on the variable - `R.remove(1)` and `new_item.set.remove(1)` have to behave the same way.

This also means that:

```
R = set(range(0,8))
for i in range(0,8):
    items.append(N(i,R,8))
```

probably has a subtle bug. `R` never gets reassigned here, and so every namedtuple in `items` gets the same set. You can confirm this by noticing that `items[0].set is items[1].set` is True. So, anytime you mutate any of them - or R - the modification would show up everywhere (they're all just different names for the same object).

This is a problem that usually comes up when you do something like

```
a = [[]] * 3
a[0].append(2)
```

and a will now be `[[2], [2], [2]]`. There are two ways around this general problem:

First, be very careful to create a *new* mutable object when you assign it, unless you do deliberately want an alias. In the nested lists example, the usual solution is to do `a = [[] for _ in range(3)]`. For your sets in tuples, move the line `R = ...` to *inside* the loop, so it gets reassigned to a *new* set for each `namedtuple`.

The second way around this is to use immutable types. Make `R` a `frozenset`, and the ability to add and remove elements goes away.

Comment: Yes you are right, i suffered above problems a few days ago when I started python, though in this one i wanted all elements to share the set, so that i need to change only 1 and can check results in others. And thanks for the answer now i got better idea of the objects in python

Answer (score 0):

You mutate the set, not the tuple. And sets are mutable.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> t = (s,)
>>> l = [s]
>>> d = {42: s}
>>> t
(set([]),)
>>> l
[set([])]
>>> d
{42: set([])}
>>> s.add('foo')
>>> t
(set(['foo']),)
>>> l
[set(['foo'])]
>>> d
{42: set(['foo'])}
```